# c++ string assigned to const char* causes address out of bounds at the n-th iteration

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c++11

I have this problem with an "Address 0x4811 out of bounds", which I suspect to be caused by a `std::string` passed to a `const char*`. The weird thing is that, this happens only after thousands of iterations. I'll try to make things clearer.

I have a function that compares two strings "character-by-character" in order to obtain a lexicographical order of a vector of strings (Code based on the "[Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.DaveKoelle.com)" implementation by Dirk Jagdmann)

```
int compareChar(const char *l, const char *r) {
    enum mode_t {
        STRING, NUMBER
    } mode;

    mode = STRING;

    while(*l && *r) {
        if(mode == STRING) {
            char l_char, r_char;
            while((l_char=*l) && (r_char=*r)) {
                // check if this are digit characters
                const bool l_digit=isDigit(l_char), r_digit=isDigit(r_char);
                // if both characters are digits, we continue in NUMBER mode
                if(l_digit && r_digit) {
                    mode=NUMBER;
                    break;
                }
                // if only the left character is a digit
                if(l_digit) return -1;
                // if only the right character is a digit
                if(r_digit) return +1;
                // compute the difference of both characters
                const int diff=l_char - r_char;
                // if they differ we have a result
                if(diff != 0) return diff;
                // otherwise process the next characters
                ++l;
                ++r;
    }
        } else { // mode==NUMBER
            // get the left number
            char *end;
            unsigned long l_int= strtoul(l, &end, 0);
            l=end;

            // get the right number
            unsigned long r_int= strtoul(r, &end, 0);
            r=end;

            while(*l && isDigit(*l)) {
                l_int=l_int*10 + *l-'0';
                ++l;
            }

            while(*r && isDigit(*r)) {
                r_int=r_int*10 + *r-'0';
        ++r;
            }

            // if the difference is not equal to zero, we have a comparison result
            const long diff=l_int-r_int;
            if(diff != 0) return diff;

            // otherwise we process the next substring in STRING mode
            mode=STRING;
        }
    }

    if(*r) return -1;
    if(*l) return +1;
    return 0;
}
```

This function is used many many times in an application that reads biological data and has to search and compare objects by their names or their symbol. Names and symbols are `std::string`, thus a usage example is:

```
bool operator<(const Gene& g) const {
    if( (compareChar(chrom.c_str(), g.chrom.c_str()) < 0 ) )
        return true;
    else
        if( (compareChar(chrom.c_str(), g.chrom.c_str())) == 0 )
            if(entrez_ID == g.getId()) return true;
            else if(start_p < g.getStart()) return true;
            else return false;
        else return false;
}
```

Specifically, the above snippet is an overloading of the `operator<`, used for ordering Gene objects. I use it in my code with the `std::sort` algorithm

```
for(genes_it=chrGenes.begin(); genes_it!=chrGenes.end(); ++genes_it)
    if( ((*genes_it).getStart() > ((*conns_it).getF2Start()-const_value)) &&
            ((*genes_it).getStart() < (*conns_it).getF2Start()) )
        bf_gene.push_back((*genes_it));

if(bf_gene.size() > 1) {
    std::sort( bf_gene.begin(), bf_gene.end() );
    bf_gene.erase( std::unique(bf_gene.begin(), bf_gene.end()), bf_gene.end() );
}
```

Well, it normally works like a charm, since yesterday when I lunched a longer simulations, and after 30 minutes run the application stopped with a segfault. Checking with *gdb*, this is the response:

```
(anonymous namespace)::compareChar (l=0x4811 <Address 0x4811 out of bounds>, r=0x9b9ec8 "chr17") at common.hpp:193
193             while(*l && *r) {

#0  (anonymous namespace)::compareChar (l=0x4811 <Address 0x4811 out of bounds>, r=0x9b9ec8 "chr17") at common.hpp:193
#1  0x0000000000410883 in Gene::operator< (this=0x8b4575b0, g=...) at Gene.hpp:222
#2  0x00000000004150a7 in std::__unguarded_partition<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Gene*, std::vector<Gene, std::allocator<Gene> > >, Gene> (__first=<value optimized out>, 
__last=<value optimized out>, __pivot=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:2209
#3  0x0000000000415242 in std::__introsort_loop<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Gene*, std::vector<Gene, std::allocator<Gene> > >, long> (__first=..., __last=..., __depth_limit=7)
at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:2268
#4  0x000000000040e4e7 in sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Gene*, std::vector<Gene, std::allocator<Gene> > > > (this=0x620ee0, id=<value optimized out>, sc_limit=3)
at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:5220
#5  Gene::findConnections (this=0x620ee0, id=<value optimized out>, sc_limit=3) at Gene.cpp:1135
#6  0x000000000041a36b in main (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>) at testth.cpp:30
```

Well, the problem is clearly there but I can't figure out why it happens after 30 minutes of execution. Furthermore, it happens all the times with the same `*l` content (as I can check from the application's log file). I don't understand how it can be an "out of bounds" error exactly in that point, insofar as it works correctly for thousands of usages.

Wondering whether it can be caused by the `std::sort` algorithm.

I will appreciate all possible hints and suggestions

Comment: what's wrong with `std::string::compare`, and secondly, why are you calling the general compare twice. re the error, that's apparently unrelated to the code shown.

Comment: Do you ever `free()` in your code ?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `std::string::compare` does not produce a lexicographical order of strings (in which chr2 comes before chr17), that's the reason for a custom function. The compare is called twice because I need that double check for the `chrom` fields to be equals while the others differ. Also, there is the possibility of a comparison which yields `> 0`, which I don't really need.

Comment: Where do you increment the pointers `l` and `r` and where is the range check?

Comment: @Faabiioo that's not what lexicographical means.

Comment: @Kabulan0lak specifically, in the `compareChar` function there is no free at all. gonna try fix it and test if it makes any difference.

Comment: Are your string objects modified from multiple threads?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak What has to be `free()`d here? You don't have to deallocate the memory returned by `c_str()`.

Comment: @jasal Not here. He has the problem after 1000+ iterations, so I was wondering if he wasn't doing infinite allocation without free

Comment: My guess is the `string` associated to the out of bounds `const char*` has been deallocated already. What is `chrom`? Is it a global variable? Member variable?

Comment: @jasal `l` and `r` are incremented after evaluating their content; the range check is with the `while(*l && *r)`, checking the elements are not NULL.
chrom is a member variable of the class Gene, and nothing is deallocated before: when the error happens, the `l` and `r` values are read from a vetcor of Gene through an iterator

Comment: A stupid question, do you have a '\0' char at the end of the string you're passing? If you dynamically allocated the memory for *l I hope you added '\0' at the end else your function will just continue scratching the memory and who knows what it can do...

Comment: @Survaf93 actually, every time I use the above function, a simply transform a `std::string` to a `const char*` using the function `c_str()`, which in turn returns a const pointer to null-terminated contents

Comment: We need more information to find the problem. Please post the context where the operator is embedded, specifically the definition of `chrom` and other functions accessing that string. Also show the full compare function.

Comment: @Faabiioo if your function only compares them and doesn't modify their values why don't you just transfer char instead of char*.

Comment: If you are under development, sometimes, this kind of error are due to memory alignment. For example, if you have removed an unused variable or function from the header. Make does not recompile the object. After a long computation you can have weird errors. You should recompile the whole library. Just in case.

Comment: @jasal, I edited my question with some more details concerning the comparing function and the context where it is used. `chrom` is defined ad `std::string chrom` and is a member of the class `Gene`. it is accessed in three ways: a trivial getter, a trivial setter and the comparing function above. and NO, at the moment the code is plain sequential code

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi thanks for pointing it out, but no important variables removed from headers. Anyway I recompiled the whole application. Concerning memory alignment, how can I be sure memory is properly aligned after thousands of iterations? the point is, I use mostly stl containers, which should guarantee a proper alignment when storing their objects. In this specific situation, a string is transformed into a const char* and passed by value to a function. and this is repeated quite many times. and then all of sudden it crashes!

Comment: Memory alignment does not matter when you're accessing `char`s because they're always aligned. The only ways to run into misalignments in C++ is to do weird stuff with pointers (of the reinterpret_cast kind) or to use extensions that implementations provide but treat as second-class citizens, like SSE types. Other C++ operations don't destroy alignment.

Answer (score 3):

The code shown doesn't seem enough to explain this behaviour. I can, however, see a few problems with it that will need fixing nonetheless.

The most striking issue is that the `operator<` provided does not define a [strict weak ordering relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings):

- it is not irreflexive: `x < x` is true;
- it is not asymmetric: there are x and y for which both `x < y` and `y < x` are true.

`std::sort` requires a strict weak ordering relation for proper operation.

Comment: I understand your point but the ordering produced satisfies my requirements. For instance, if it has to compare ('chr17','chr17'), it won't satisfy the `if` statement and will jump to the `else`, where the `==` condition is handled. At this point, as you correctly grasped, the entrez_IDs are checked because they CAN be equal; if I only check for `start1 < start2` when `chr1 == chr2` I do not get the ordering I desire.
I'm gonna edit the question adding more details

Comment: It doesn't satisfy the requirements of `std::sort`. `std::sort` doesn't care about your requirements.

Comment: I edited my question with some more details. Concerning the _strict weak ordering relation_, what are the consequences of not using a proper comparing function? I searched through the c++ documentation but nothing is specified

Comment: The consequences are undefined behaviour. `std::sort` works under the assumption the comparison defines a SWO. If you violate that assumption `std::sort` doesn't work, other than by sheer luck.

Comment: Though I'm curious what kind of requirements you have that require a string to be *less than itself*.

Comment: The Gene object is composed of several "fields": chrom, symbol, start, stop, entrezId. there might be many genes with the same chrom but with different symbol; several genes have the same chrom and the same symbol but different start point. 
and I don't get your _less than itself_...

Comment: Ooops, I meant "gene" not "string". It's right in my answer: `x < x` will be true for any x. Any gene will be counted as less than itself because it has the same chrom and the same entrezId, so `operator<` returns true.